# Looping through Angular QueryList

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops

So I want to get all the images in my component in an array, so I am using Angular's `@ViewChildren` which returns a `QueryList` of `ElementRef`:

```js
@ViewChildren('img', { read: ElementRef }) images: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

However, when ever I try to loop through the list am can't ever seem to get hold of the `nativeElement`. I am calling this in `ngAfterViewInit()`

```js
this.images.forEach((img, index) => console.log("Image", img.nativeElement));
```

I don't get anything in the `console.log`, no error nothing.

This in turn does work:

```js
console.log("this.images", this.images);
```

Below is an image of the log of `console.log("this.images", this.images)`:

[image]

Here the `html`:

```html
<div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let exhibit of exhibits; let i = index">
   <app-exhibit-images exhibitImagesId="{{ exhibit.fields.eventImages[0].sys.id }}" [eventPicturesStart]="eventPicturesStart" (sendEndEventPictures)="getEndEventImages($event)"></app-exhibit-images>
   <div id="exhibit-{{i}}"class="gallery__content" [ngClass]="{'show-event-pictures' : eventPicturesStart}">
      <div class="gallery__poster" [ngClass]="{'gallery-expand' : isGalleryExpanded }">
         <figure class="poster__image">
            <picture>
               <source srcset="{{ exhibit.fields.photo.fields.file.url }}" type="img/png">
               <img #img src="{{ exhibit.fields.photo.fields.file.url }}" alt="{{ exhibit.fields.photo.fields.description }}">
            </picture>
         </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery__text" [ngClass]="{'gallery-expand' : isGalleryExpanded }">
         <button class="gallery-expand-button" (click)="expandGallery()"></button>
         <h2 class="gallery__heading">{{ exhibit.fields.title }}</h2>
         <h3 class="gallery__subheading">{{ exhibit.fields.subTitle }}</h3>
         <h4 class="gallery__artist">{{ exhibit.fields.artist }}</h4>
         <p class="gallery__description" *ngIf="exhibit.fields.description">{{ exhibit.fields.description }}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to do `this.images.toArray().forEach(...)`

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have added the HTML

Comment: Is `this.images` an empty array?

Comment: @miselking No it is not empty. I have just added a screenshot of the log.

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have tried that and it simply returns an empty Array as such `Array [ ]`

Comment: @Chellappanவ Yup I have done it so

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Check the length of same and let us know. this.images.length.

Comment: @HarshadVekariya Mhm `this.images.length` returns `0`

Comment: so you got your answer. there is nothing in that, hence loop do not run. try subscribe on that one and see when element is added.  There is changes prop which return subscription. https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList

Comment: I'm confused, there is something in there no? Because when I run `console.log("this.images", this.images);` I do get an object of all the `img` tags in the component (see screenshot of log)

Comment: `console.log` can only show you the current state of the object, not the object of the snapshot in time of when it was called.

Comment: @Chellappanவ Here is a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzeehf How can I get all the images?

Comment: You have to place template variable on element like this <img #img *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]" [src]="'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random='+i"> forked stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vq6qmy

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with `@ContentChildren`. The solution was to subscribe to the [`changes`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#changes) observable of the `QueryList`.

Essentially, this will trigger whenever any of the state of the children changes. Normally this wouldn't be necessary but if your list of children is loaded in via a GET, this ensures the `QueryList` is data is loaded before executing on it. Its important to note the subscription will fire again whenever the any of the children's content changes.

```js
@ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => ChildComponent), { descendants: true })
private children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    // subscribe to changes
    this.children.changes.subscribe(children => {
        children.forEach(child => {
            // do something with each child...
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jakopo Sciampi already mentioned a possibility is also to use the .toArray() function on the QueryList.

```
this.images.toArray().forEach((img, index) => {
            console.log('Image', img.nativeElement);
        });
```

Just make sure that you don't call the command to early => there will be no elements => the loop is not excecuted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
this.images["_result"].forEach((img, index) => {
  console.log('Image', img.nativeElement);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't call your loop in `ngAfterViewInit`, use `ngAfterViewChecked` instead. This will be triggered AFTER your child components are checked.

See [lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Bad idea. Read please: "Called after the ngAfterViewInit() and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked()". So `ngAfterViewInit` needs to be used.