# Angular directive to check if all images have been fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

So I have a gallery slide section in my Angular app and I am using Swiperjs for all the sliding stuff. Anyhow so for Swiperjs to work properly I need all the images to be loaded before Swiperjs is initialised. Hence my question, how can I create a directive that will look for all the images in the component and its child component and check if all the images have been loaded?

So far I have a directive that checks for all the Image tags in the parent component `GalleryComponent` and logs "Img Loaded". Below is my directive:

```js
import { Directive,ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img'
})
export class ImagesLoadedDirective {
  constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener("load") imageLoaded() {
    console.log("img loaded");
    /* Can I do something like "return true" for every image that loaded? And how would I register that in my Gallery Component*/
  }
}
```

I have included the directive in my `GalleryComponent` as such:

```js
  @ViewChildren(ImagesLoadedDirective) images:QueryList<ImagesLoadedDirective>;
```

I suppose the next step is to somehow save each image that has been loaded, and once that is done
I can say something like `this.allImagesLoaded = true`, then initialize Swiperjs? Appreciated any input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `EventEmitter` to notify subscribers that image has been loaded. Then just combine all those `Observables` through `forkJoin` in your root component. Once all images are loaded you will be notified in `forkJoin` subscription.

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'img',
})
export class ImgLoadedDirective {
  @Output() loaded = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('load')
  @HostListener('error')
  imageLoaded() {
    this.loaded.emit();
    this.loaded.complete();
  }
}
```

**parent.ts**

```
@ViewChildren(ImgLoadedDirective) images: QueryList<ImgLoadedDirective>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  forkJoin(this.images.map(imgDir => imgDir.loaded)).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('all images have been loaded');
  });
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/5e4AHQkdjeRXf7O1bg2g?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: thanks this just what I was looking for and I understand the idea of it as it is. I am unable to make it work in my app however. I have done it exactly as your answer and I am not getting an errors but for some reason it never gets to the point where `console.log('all images have been loaded')` is executed, any idea why that might be?

Comment: Hard to predict, can you please replicate this issue in stackblitz? Maybe you forgot to declare ImgLoadedDirective in your NgModule

Comment: The Directive is declared in my NgModule. I tried to replicate hte issue on Stackblitz too but on there everything works as its supposed to. Here is an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629180/looping-through-angular-querylist, and i think its linked. There `this.images.forEach((img, index) => console.log("Image", img.nativeElement));`, it's also was as if it never rendered in my app, but no error nothing. What could this be? It's very odd

Comment: Try to reduce unrelated code in your application and put rest to the stackblitz. Or you can create a small github repo so that I can take a look

Comment: How to you get `exhibits` in your application? I guess you're getting it from API?

Comment: Yes I get `exhibits` from API. I am using Contentful Headless CMS. I will try and recreate a stackblitz.

Comment: That's the reason why it doesn't work for you. If will create an example of how to deal with it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xy3ps?file=src/app/app.component.ts